# Convert Local time to UTC for Spanish Language

Tags: android

> I converted local time to GMT/UTC using following method(find the solution on stack overflow).It's working fine when a date is for the English language.

```
public static Date localToGMT() {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault());
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date gmt = new Date(sdf.format(date));
    return gmt;
}
```

> sdf.format(date) => it's given proper date in spanish language.
>
> But for this in Spanish language "new Date(String date)" not working.
>   I want it should work for English and Spanish language.

Any solution for this?

Comment: What you do here does not make sense. A `Date` does not have a time zone. it represents a certain moment in time. Only when you format it into a string representation comes the time zone into play. This is because the same moment is represented differently in different time zones.

Comment: @Henry I understand Date does not have time zone but when I change device default language from English to Spanish new Date(sdf.format(date)) at this line app crash. I don't know why this happen.Any solution for this?